# Installing Android things sample code in Smart Phone

Tags: android, android-things

I tried to install the google UART sample project in my smart phone but am getting the the following error:
unable to find the shared library 'androidthings:1.0'. 
Do i need android things enabled device to run this?

Comment: Are you trying to install an app developed for another OS?

Comment: no.  i just want to install the sample uart app that we get in android studio in my smart phone and get the uart device list

Comment: Android and Android Things are different OSs. Android does not have PeripheralManager and UART APIs.

Comment: So do i need a device with Android things to run this ?

Comment: yes.............

Answer (score 0):

As phones are not Android Things devices, the Android Things library will not be found. However, as Android Things and Android for phones have the same base, you are able to modify the sample project in a few ways to get it to work.

You'll need to remove all Android Things references in the `build.gradle`, `AndroidManifest.xml`, and in the code.

Comment: i wanted to access the PeripheralManager which i cant access without AndroidThings library.

Comment: You can't use the PeripheralManager on a phone.