# How can I use GPIO pins on an android smartphone app?

Tags: android, kotlin, gpio

I'm trying to list and control GPIO pins with my android smartphone app. The pins are connected to the phone with a USB cable. I found and tried using PeripheralManager, but it's not working.

I tried using it like this:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val manager = PeripheralManager.getInstance()
    }
```

but I get this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
```

```
at com.google.android.things.pio.PeripheralManager.getInstance(PeripheralManager.java:21)
```

I have added android things to my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
implementation 'com.google.android.things:androidthings:1.0'
}
```

I also tried to add the library to my app:

```
<application>
   <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.things"/>
</application>
```

but it gives me this error:

```
Installation failed due to: 'INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY: Reconciliation failed...: Reconcile failed: Package requires unavailable shared library com.google.android.things; failing!'
```

I found a Stack overflow source that mentioned that Android Things doesn't work with phones. [Android Things and phones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54667901/installing-android-things-sample-code-in-smart-phone#comment96190733_54677035)

So is there another way to use GPIO pins on a smartphone app?

Comment: Have you tried to provide the `com.google.android.things` yourself, in a form of a shared library or some such?

Comment: I tried it now but I'm not sure that I'm doing it correctly. I created a new android library module. I added "implementation 'com.google.android.things:androidthings:1.0'" to it. I added the module to my projects dependencies from the project structure. And now my build gradle has "implementation project(path: ':myAndroidThings')". I'm not sure how to utilize the library, but like this, the PeripheralManager is still not working.

Comment: This bit is troubling `java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!` - that means that `PeripheralManager.getInstance()` is stubbed in your OS distribution, and that you're either lacking a shared library for it, or you're lacking stuff deeper down, possibly all the way down to the kernel driver. [Heres a similar example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54963705/peripheralmanager-class-not-found)

Comment: It's also entirely possible that you're missing those things just on your phone, as it can be a vendor-specific thing.